# Airflow authetication with LDAP based on owner

Tags: security, ldap, airflow, rbac

I am trying to configure my Airflow (version 2.10) LDAP authentication with RBAC.
UI access is restricted by the AD groups (multiple groups for Python Developer, ML Developer, etc.)
Members belonging to a particular group only should be able to view the DAGs created by fellow group members while the other group members shouldn't be.

Able to provide access to users via AD groups but all the users are able to see all the DAGs created. I want to restrict this access based on the defined set of owners, (this can be achieved by switching off the LDAP and creating users directly in Airflow, but I want it with AD groups.)

added `fiter_by_owner=True` in airflow.cfg file, seems nothing is effected.

Any thoughts on this.

EDIT1:
From FAB,
we can configure roles & then map it to AD groups as below:

```
FAB_ROLES = {
    "ReadOnly_Altered": [
        [".*", "can_list"],
        [".*", "can_show"],
        [".*", "menu_access"],
        [".*", "can_get"],
        [".*", "can_info"]
    ]
}

FAB_ROLES_MAPPING = {
    1: "ReadOnly_Altered"
}
```

And to use this, I assume we need to have the endpoints created from the application end similar to `can_list`, `can_show` .

In the case of Airflow, I am unable to find the end-points that provides access based on owner (or based on tags). I believe if we have them, I can map it to roles & then to AD groups accordingly.

Answer (score 1):

With newer versions of Airlfow you can map LDAP groups to Airflow Groups.

Owner is an old and currently defunct feature which is deprecated.

You can see some examples about FAB configuration (Flask Application Builder implements all authentication features):

https://flask-appbuilder.readthedocs.io/en/latest/security.html

See the part which starts with:

`You can give FlaskAppBuilder roles based on LDAP roles (note, this requires AUTH_LDAP_SEARCH to be set):`

From the docs:

```
# a mapping from LDAP DN to a list of FAB roles
AUTH_ROLES_MAPPING = {
    "cn=fab_users,ou=groups,dc=example,dc=com": ["User"],
    "cn=fab_admins,ou=groups,dc=example,dc=com": ["Admin"],
}

# the LDAP user attribute which has their role DNs
AUTH_LDAP_GROUP_FIELD = "memberOf"

# if we should replace ALL the user's roles each login, or only on registration
AUTH_ROLES_SYNC_AT_LOGIN = True

# force users to re-auth after 30min of inactivity (to keep roles in sync)
PERMANENT_SESSION_LIFETIME = 1800
```

See here about roles (including custom roles) https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/stable/security/access-control.html

Comment: Thanks for your response, I updated the question so as to explain the problem even better. Please check the edit1

Comment: No endpoints are needed.You need to enable LDAP search and map the right group from LDAP to the right Role in Airflow.  Then the Roles have the right set of permissions that you can also modify (but in Airflow): https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/stable/security/access-control.html

Comment: I updated the answer to explain it better.

Comment: This part was understood & was already implemented, your answer explains about mapping a role to AD group. I am looking at creation of new roles, which allows only an user having access to the role(in turn it is provided by AD group) that has access defined based on owner value in DAG code. Is this possible with the given end-points (https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/stable/security/access-control.html) ?? If so, then how

Comment: no. Owner has no meaning in airflow any more other than informative value. You can only give permissions based on DAG_id as described here: https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/stable/security/access-control.html#dag-level-permissions